# Typescript error when using object with useState in Nuxt3

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

I would like to have an empty object for the initial value ,
and add keys and values later.

Is it possible to do this with useState  in Nuxt3?

However, the typescript in the code below gave me an error.
How can I fix this code?

Thanks in advance.

*error message*

```
Argument of type 'Ref<{} | AnimalContext>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ref<AnimalContext>'.
  Type '{} | AnimalContext' is not assignable to type 'AnimalContext'.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'AnimalContext': name, age, sizets(2345)
```

*composables/useStateAnimal.ts*

```js
import type { Ref } from 'vue';

interface AnimalContext {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    size: string;
    [key: string]: string | number;
}

export const useStateAnimal = () => {
    // state
    const data: Ref<AnimalContext | {}> = useState('animal', () => ({}));
    // state update function
    const updateAnimal = (data: Ref<AnimalContext>) => (keyName: string, newVal: string|number) => {
        data.value[keyName] = newVal;
    }

    return {
        data: readonly(data), 
        updateAnimal: updateProject(data), // I get an error here
    }
}
```